# Trigger a sub when a specific module is being viewed in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Is there an event trigger or something similar that enables me to launch a sub when the user opens a specific module? Something like
`Application.OpenModule1` -> `Call SpecificSub`. To my knowledge there is no such `Application` event or anything that would achieve something similar. If anyone could tell me for sure if this is possible or not, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you're talking about event handling within the Visual Basic Editor itself?

No, there isn't any functionality for such events.

Comment: Thanks, that's all I needed, now I won't need to waste more time searching for something that doesn't exist.